# How to set a server URL to connect to for a Meteor Cordova app?

Tags: cordova, meteor

I build my meteor cordova app with `meteor build ../output --server=myserverprod.com:8080`

But when I remote debugging I see that it still tries to connect, even for the first time, to my local server 192.x.x.x instead of the URL I put in the command line.

I have already set a server environment variable as ROOT_URL=myserverprod.com:8080

Comment: You might need to add the protocol to the server name, eg --server=http://myserverprod.com:8080 or --server=https://myserverprod.com:8080

Comment: If the server is running behind a firewall and/or proxy (most likely) you will need to set ROOT_URL=http://myserverprod.com:8080 as well, so it knows it's own address

Comment: I don't get your first point on the protocol. You mean put http behind? I have already tried. Also ROOT_URL on the server is already set.
The thing is when I first start the app the first connection the app want to establish is 192.168.X.X, but not the ROOT_URL as I stated before.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I typed it wrong. I can't see what you are doing wrong, unless there is a settings file or another environment variable that is confusing it, or a bit of code that is requesting something from your local ip

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are 'remote debugging' leads me to believe you are using meteor run android | android-device

If that is the case, you are NOT using the apk that was built and saved in ../output and as such your app is using the server IT WAS DEPLOYED FROM... and ignores the --server flag... :o(

If you install the apk (you will need to sign it etc) then the app will connect to the remote server, but you won't be able to remote debug it as far as I know.

Comment: No, I am using the apk in output. Indeed I am thinking of an issue. See: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7849

Comment: Can you check in ../output/android/project/res/xml/config.xml, what is <access origin> set to?

Comment: <access origin="*://192.168.X.X" />
<access origin="*" />

Comment: so,  your build failed, I think because there should not be = between flag and attribute. Try build again with `meteor build ../output --server http://myserverprod.com:8080` (no equals sign and include http://)

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is a problem, there is an issue on the Meteor github page. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7849

Here is a workaround from @dagatsoin

Reproducing the problem

- Reset or create a new project
- Add android platform
- meteor run android device
- meteor build ../apk --server http://whatever.com:3000 and install the apk with adb install ../apk/...

Remote debug shows the app is trying to connect to the old local url.
It is like meteor build keep the previous url (so the local one)

Workaround

- meteor run android-device --mobile-server http://whatever.com:3000
- meteor build ../apk --server http://whatever.com:3000 and install the apk with adb install ../apk/...

Remote debug shows the app connect to whatever.com